# Word Cloud scaled with X1 frequency positive blue negative red. Color intensity will be based on X1

Tags: r, colors, frequency, word-cloud

I want to plot 4 wordcloud based on my data 1, 2,3,4. let's the column name x1, x2, x3, x4
I can plot it but I want the positive valued word will be blue and negative valued will be red. The size and color intensity will be based on their X1.

[image]

```
data <- read.csv("RotatedComponentMatrix.csv")
```

[image]

Thank you in advance.